# Delete an item in a listView (from a service that broadcast an intent) without knowing its position

Tags: android, android-listview, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that synchronize data every minute. When a data is modified/created, I send a broadcast to my Activity in order to update my ListView.

To update the view, i want to delete it and recreate with right values but i don't know its position, i only have the content of its textViews.

Activity :

```
public void onCreate{
...
this.registerReceiver(this.updateListReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            "com.android.updatelist"));
}

BroadcastReceiver updateListReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String id = intent.getExtras().getString("AccountId");
        String name = intent.getExtras().getString("AccountName");
        boolean isNew = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("isNew");

        if (isNew) {
            Account accountInList = new Account(id, name, null, null, null,
                    null);
            adapter.add(accountInList);
        } else {

        }
    }
};
```

Service :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction("com.android.updatelist");
                                intent.putExtra("AccountId",
                                        updatedAccount.getAccountId());
                                intent.putExtra("AccountName",
                                        updatedAccount.getName());
                                intent.putExtra("isNew", true);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Adapter :

```
public class AccountNameListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account> {

private final Context context;
private final int layoutResourceId;
private final ArrayList<Account> data;
private final TableLayout table;
private final TextView tableName;
private final TextView tableIndustry;
private final TextView tablePhone;
private final TextView tableWebsite;
final AccountBDD accountBdd;

public AccountNameListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        ArrayList<Account> data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    table = (TableLayout) ((Activity) context)
            .findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    tableName = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    tableIndustry = (TextView) ((Activity) context)
            .findViewById(R.id.IndustryText);
    tablePhone = (TextView) ((Activity) context)
            .findViewById(R.id.PhoneText);
    tableWebsite = (TextView) ((Activity) context)
            .findViewById(R.id.WebsiteText);

    accountBdd = SQLiteApplication.getAccountBdd();

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    AccountHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new AccountHolder();

        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setFocusable(true);

        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
        holder.txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (AccountHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            table.setVisibility(0);

            String id = data.get(position).getAccountId();
            Account displayAccount = accountBdd.getAccountWithAccountID(id);

            tableName.setText(displayAccount.getName());
            tableIndustry.setText(displayAccount.getIndustry());
            tablePhone.setText(displayAccount.getPhone());
            tableWebsite.setText(displayAccount.getWebsite());
        }

    });

    holder.txtName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtId.setText(data.get(position).getAccountId());

    ImageButton img = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
    img.setTag(position);

    return convertView;
}

static class AccountHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtId;
}
```

}

How can i do please ?

Comment: Where are you getting your info, local or network?

Comment: i am getting my info from the network (htpp requests) and then i insert/update my SQLite Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in the adapter that takes the account_id as an input. It should look like this:

```
private void deleteData(int account_id) {
   for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
      //search for the id and delete it from the data
   }
   notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

and from the activity that you receive the `BroadcastReceiver` just call this method and you are ok. It is much quicker than you think.

UPDATE: The `Account` is an object. The remove does not work that way, because the address memory always changes.

Try to find the position of the exact object among the data and try data.remove(position). Something like this, instead of `getAccountByID(int accountid)` implement this:

```
private int getPositionFromID(int accountid) {
   for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
       if(data.get(i).getAccountID() == accountID)
           return i; //if you have a match
   }
   return -1; //error code, that is not found
}
```

and then use the position to remove the exact spot:

```
private void deleteData(int account_id) {
   int position = getPositionFromID(int accountid);
   if(position == -1) {
      //handle error
   } else {
      data.remove(position); 
      notifyDatasetChanged();
   }
}
```

Here you are! Now you have a full copy-paste example! I have done it many times, no need to mess up `CursorAdapter` or anything like that, pure hard-coded java. I am pretty sure this actually works, if it doesn't work in your example I will advise you to debug and make sure everything is ok, because I guess there is something else wrong with your code, and not that the adapter is not populated.

Comment: It doesn't work.  I have tried in my Adapter :

public void deleteViewWithAccountId(String AccountId) {
      
    Account account = getAccountWithId(AccountId);
    data.remove(account);
   }
  }
  notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

But the row is not deleted

Comment: Awesome, it works perfectly, simple and fast ! It was my bad, my service sent a broadcast to prevent there was a new account (not present in the list yet) so i had not a valid position. Thanks man !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete any item, without knowing its position.

One solution which is not feasible but effective is: after receiving a broadcast, recreate everything. That means, whichever part is getting updated, flush that part and again create it with new values.

For ex.: if your list is getting updated, remove all items from list, then add all new values, and call `notifyDataSetChange` method on adapter.

Comment: Yea, it might not be the best behavior but it works. Switching how the database is accessed could also help if using `CursorAdapter` with a `CursorLoader` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So I am basing this off my question, but you aren't going to like it. In my opinion the best way to do this is to actually use a `CursorAdapter` with a `CursorLoader` that refreshes whats in the database. So you don't have to do the work basically. Once you get the info from the network and the database is updated, you just refresh the adapter and the new info will be reflected. In your case, you cannot change anything in the `ListView` without knowing where it beloings. But with the method I just told you, `ListView`'s `setAdapter()` can hold the `CursorAdapter` and you can just refresh it. But it will require some reworking of code.

Comment: i think this is a way to do it, i'll try it. I have to rework my code before